# Bootstrap alert append and fade in/out

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, bootstrap-4

I want to add Bootstrap alert dynamically with `fadeIn` effect and `fadeOut` effect on close, I tried:

```js
function alert(title, text, type) {
  var html = $("<div class='alert alert-dismissible hide fade " + type + "'><strong>" + title + "</strong> " + text + "<a href='#' class='close float-close' data-dismiss='alert' aria-label='close'>×</a></div>");
  $('body').append(html);
  html.addClass('in show');
}


$('#EMail').click(function() {
  alert('Error!', 'Your Email is not valid', 'alert-danger');
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<link href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.1.1/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" integrity="sha384-WskhaSGFgHYWDcbwN70/dfYBj47jz9qbsMId/iRN3ewGhXQFZCSftd1LZCfmhktB" crossorigin="anonymous">
<script src="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.1.1/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-smHYKdLADwkXOn1EmN1qk/HfnUcbVRZyYmZ4qpPea6sjB/pTJ0euyQp0Mk8ck+5T" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<input type="text" id="EMail" />
```

With this, close work successfully but append with `fadeIn` effect not working. How can I append Bootstrap alert in document with fadeIn effect?

Note that, I don't need jQuery `fadeIn` or `fadeOut` I want to do this only with standard bootstrap `class` such `fade` + `in` or `out`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Updated function with a setTimeout

```js
function alert(title, text, type) {
  var html = $("<div class='alert alert-dismissible hide fade in " + type + "'><strong>" + title + "</strong> " + text + "<a href='#' class='close float-close' data-dismiss='alert' aria-label='close'>×</a></div>");
  $('body').append(html);
  setTimeout(function() {
 html.addClass('show');
  },0);
}


$('#EMail').click(function() {
  alert('Error!', 'Your Email is not valid', 'alert-danger');
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<link href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.1.1/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" integrity="sha384-WskhaSGFgHYWDcbwN70/dfYBj47jz9qbsMId/iRN3ewGhXQFZCSftd1LZCfmhktB" crossorigin="anonymous">
<script src="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.1.1/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-smHYKdLADwkXOn1EmN1qk/HfnUcbVRZyYmZ4qpPea6sjB/pTJ0euyQp0Mk8ck+5T" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<input type="text" id="EMail" />
```

Comment: As I said, I don't want use `fadeIn()`

Comment: I am not sure if there is any bootstrap way of doing it the way you are doing. It was possible if you had the dismissble alert in DOM already. But not with the current code, So the only way I found was to add a setTimeout to the adding of show class.

Comment: Thanks, it work fine, I will accept if I don't get very pure solution in few minutes later.A question, how setTimeOut make it work?

Comment: Yeah even I want to see a cleaner way of doing it. Basically, from what I guessed is because you are adding the element in the view and the class that has opacity 1 css property, both at the same  time, so basically there is no opacity change for animation to show. So the animation doesn't really seem to occur. But  when I added settimeout, it first added the element with opacity 0 , then after settimeout added the class with opacity 1, and hence the transition effects were visible.